# Objective C - Implement a method using an out id*

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, out

I am currently developing an Objective C class `ClassA` and I am trying to implement a method similar to `NSURL` method `- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id __nullable * __nonnull)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(out NSError ** __nullable)error` that uses `out id *`:

My Method is: `- (BOOL)changeString:(out id *)theString toString:(NSString *)newString`

And I want my method to set `theString` to (NSString*) `newString's` value

I my method to be used like this:

```
id inputString;
[[ClassA alloc] changeString:&inputString toString:@"New String"];
```

`inputString` should now be set to "New String" (as id *)

How can I do this in `- (BOOL)changeString:(out id *)theString toString:(NSString *)newString`?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use unspecified `id` although the passed parameter is clearly  `NSString`?

Comment: I don't believe u can pass out an out NSString * can you? I thought It was only id?

Comment: Of course you can (see all `NSError` parameters) but you need two asterisks `(out NSString **)theString`.

Comment: Ok thanks, well can you just give me an example of an out NSString please, so my method has (out NSString **)theString and set theString to newString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

```
- (BOOL)changeString:(NSString * _Nonnull *)theString 
            toString:(NSString *)newString  {
    *theString = newString;
    return YES;
}
```

And use it:

```
NSString *inputString;
BOOL result = [self changeString:&inputString toString:@"Hello World"];
NSLog(@"%d - %@", result, inputString);
```

---

`inputString` is not required to be `nil`, you can even pass a value

```
- (BOOL)changeString:(NSString * _Nonnull *)theString 
            toString:(NSString *)newString  {

    *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", *theString, newString];
    return YES;
}

NSString *inputString = @"Hello";
BOOL result = [self changeString:&inputString toString:@"World"];
NSLog(@"%d - %@", result, inputString);
```

Comment: Just wondering, can an `out` variable read data if the variable inputed had a value or is it just set to null?

Comment: You can also pass a value. `inputString` is just a pointer. I updated the answer.